# Can't solve an Integral, how to ask questions.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, soft-question

\begin{equation*}
\int ^{\frac{\pi }{2}}_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\cos x}{e^{x} +1} dx
\end{equation*}

Is there a generally accepted format to ask questions on MSE?
Also can someone tell me how to write integrals, fractions and equations from keyboard....
Thanks!

Comment: People generally use MathJax. But since you are new, you could use this site - https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: Try the substitution x=-t.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(x)$ be an even function of $x$. Then:
$$
I=\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{f(x)dx}{e^x+1}\stackrel{x\to-t}=\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{f(t)dt}{e^{-t}+1}.
$$

$$
2I=\int_{-a}^{a}\left[\frac{1}{e^x+1}+\frac{1}{e^{-x}+1}\right]f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) dx.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

To write your integral,

```
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+e^{x}} \right) \, dx. $$
```

produces

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+e^{x}} \right) \, dx.$$

Also appreciated is when you state what you have tried, for example:

$$\begin{aligned} 1.& \text{ substitution} \\ 2.& \text{ integration-by-parts} \\ 3.& \textit{ etc.}\end{aligned}$$